# how to run php script inside javascript if statment

Tags: javascript, php

are there are any way to run php script inside javascript if statement without post  parameters for example i have this if statement inside my javascript function

```
if(brd_side == COLOURS.WHITE) {
  $("#GameStatus").text("GAME OVER {player one win}");return BOOL.TRUE;
} else {
  $("#GameStatus").text("GAME OVER {player two win}");return BOOL.TRUE;
}
```

i want to call php script inside the if statement to update the player points on my database using php and my sql

to be something like that

```
if(brd_side == COLOURS.WHITE) {
  $("#GameStatus").text("GAME OVER {player one win}");return BOOL.TRUE;
   //playeronescript.php
} else {
  $("#GameStatus").text("GAME OVER {player two win}");return BOOL.TRUE;
  //playertwoscript.php
}
```

I using symfony framework so i can't write the javascript function inside the php and calling the function with something like that `<?php playeronefunction?>`

Comment: You can use AJAX for this kind of tasks.

Comment: They are separate languages. You would make an Ajax call to the php script.

Comment: are there are any way to run php script inside javascript? No, however as @Twinfriends said you can use ajax call to make it possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should perform an [AJAX call](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "playertwoscript.php",
  method: 'GET/POST',
  data: { test: "test" }
  success: function (data) {}
})
```